# How to put variable into log_config.yaml using FileHandler - Logging Python

Tags: python, windows, selenium, logging, yaml

I have a file config(.yaml) for logging in python containing a file handler that write logs in file.
It works when I put the absolute Path, but not working when i put a variable that contains the Path

```
#my_program/resources/log_config.yaml

handlers:
    file:
        class: logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
        level: DEBUG
        formatter: standard
        filename: "C:/workspace/my_program/results/errors.log"
        when: midnight
        encoding: utf8
```

I tried:

```
filename: "../results/errors.log"
```

I tried to put a variable environment

```
filename: " {{$PROJECT_HOME}}/results/errors.log"
```

output:

> ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file'
> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'logger' referenced before assignment

I need to put the PATH in an other file settings who contains all path that I use or at least use a variable ENV which contains the path

how can i put a dynamic variable into yaml file?

Comment: You can subclass `TimedRotatingFileHandler` and implement target path construction yourself, e.g. by reading env vars etc. Or you can extend YAML syntax with your own tag, like described [here](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) (search for section "Constructors, representers, resolvers").